# Displaying full details of blog posts on the homepage of a wordpress theme that does not allow it by default

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. I got this template that I want to use for my site. The template link is [here](http://themeforest.net/user/internq7/portfolio?ref=internq7). By default this template allows you to put all sorts of plugins on the homepage. Problem is I don't really want to style my blog the way the template comes. What I just want is to have the full details of my blog posts showing on the homepage and then the categories by the side. Does any know of any plugin that I can use to display blog posts full details instead of just lists (with or without thumbnails)

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage should use the file `index.php` from the theme (located in `wp-content/themes/name_of_your_theme`). Open it and search for `the_excerpt`. It should be located in the Loop, as many things related to Posts in Wordpress.

If what you want to display in the homepage is the same thing than when a single post is displayed, then open `single.php` in the same directory. That's the theme file used when displaying a single post. Search for `the_content` inside the Loop and see how it's done. You want to do the same in index.php, more or less copypasting or replacing carefully `the_excerpt` by `the_content`. Well, it'll be a little harder than that (you've to understand what you remove, replace or copy) but that's the idea.

Relevant documentation in Codex: [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) (esp. the 2nd paragraph) and [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) (answers the questions related to which file is called for Homepage, single post, a category, a page, etc)

Comment: I couldn't find the_excerpt on the index of the template. Is there any other thing I could look out for? I also renamed the single.php file to index.php but I noticed that the posts did not have titles and that the styling wasn't there. What could be happening?